# Создание COM DLL, регистрация с помощью regsvr32

Tags: c++, windows, dll, com, visual-basic

Нужен пример создания dll на языке C++, которая бы регистриролась бы с помощью regsvr32, и её можно было бы подключить к проекту на VB5.

---

В Google был, примеров куча но там библиотеку не регистрируют, а подгружают через loadLib и используют.

Comment: http://old.unick-soft.ru/Soft.cgi?type=File&id=15 пример создания ActiveX компомнента.

Comment: для COM обвязка слишком большая нужна, вручную сложно и долго, проще в VC++ создать проект ATL

Comment: Вот [неплохой цикл статей](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13601/COM-in-plain-C), где вся обвязка COM разжевывается правда для Си, но масштаб бедствия оценить можно.